# Select from many tables - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have that table construction and code sample:

[image]

```
var Tasks = db.Users
              .Where(t => t.Id == 1)
              .Where(t => t.Tables.Where(a => a.Id == 1)))
              .Select(a => a.Tasks.Select(a => a.Tasks.Text));
```

This code don't work, how can I get `Tasks.Text` when I using many `where` questions?

Thanks

Comment: `This code don't work` doesn't help a lot :) At which line it isn't working?

Comment: Yep, Visual taking error becouse the problem is in logic command. I don't know How I Can include many where command in SQL command (entity)

Comment: You need to add to end of query SelectMany : .SelectMany(x => x).

Comment: `t.Tables.Where(a => a.Id==1)` should be `t.Tables.Any(a => a.Id==1)`

Comment: I try write like this : `Select Tasks.Text where User.Id =1 and Tables.ID =1` but How I Can write it with entity?

Comment: @CodeNotFound I check this solution :)

Comment: Do you have a working sql code? We can help you to convert to linq

Comment: Nope I don't have :(

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)